# How to auto-update custom plugins in Oh My Zsh?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, plugin

I've installed [Oh My Zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) with a few custom plugins, such as [`zsh-autosuggestions`](https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-autosuggestions). Now while Oh My Zsh supports automatic [updates](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh#getting-updates), this doesn't apply to custom plugins (installed to the `custom/` subdirectory). How can I make Oh My Zsh update those as well?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Oh My Zsh upgrades are handled by the [`$ZSH/tools/upgrade.sh`](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/tools/upgrade.sh) script. To update any custom plugins (assuming those are Git clones), you can add these lines to the end of the script before the `exit` command:

```
printf "\n${BLUE}%s${RESET}\n" "Updating custom plugins"
cd custom/plugins

for plugin in */; do
  if [ -d "$plugin/.git" ]; then
     printf "${YELLOW}%s${RESET}\n" "${plugin%/}"
     git -C "$plugin" pull
  fi
done
```

Now, whenever Oh My Zsh is [updated](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh#getting-updates), your custom plugins will be updated too.

Comment: why isn't this part of OhMyZSH?

Comment: Should I put it before `exit $status` in the `$ZSH/tools/upgrade.sh` file?

Comment: @alper: Yes. That `exit` call seems a recent addition to the upgrade script.

Comment: Won't this get removed if oh-my-zsh updates this file?

Comment: Just install the "autoupdate" plugin 

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by using the [autoupdate](https://github.com/TamCore/autoupdate-oh-my-zsh-plugins) plugin.

Simply download it as a regular custom plugin, and add it to the `plugins` array in your `.zshrc` file:

```
plugins=(
  ...
  autoupdate
)
```

Follow the instructions in their [`README`](https://github.com/TamCore/autoupdate-oh-my-zsh-plugins#readme) to find out how to customize the update frequency

Comment: Does it work for you? I've installed and enabled it, reloaded zsh, but still no updates on `upgrade_oh_my_zsh`

Comment: @EugeneYarmash try `upgrade_ohl_my_zsh` or `upgrade_oh_my_zsh_custom`

Comment: I've just tried the `autoupdate` plugin, following the README instructions, and I confirm that it does NOT work when running `omz update`. It only works if you manually call `upgrade_oh_my_zsh_custom`.

Comment: it works for me, it does the autopudate with the frequency you set in the exported env var UPDATE_ZSH_DAYS and does that when you start a new shell

Answer (score 2):

Small expansion on Eugene's great answer. This will also update any themes you have:

```
# $ZSH/tools/upgrade.sh

...


printf "\n${BLUE}%s${RESET}\n" "Updating custom plugins and themes"
cd custom/
for plugin in plugins/*/ themes/*/; do
  if [ -d "$plugin/.git" ]; then
     printf "${YELLOW}%s${RESET}\n" "${plugin%/}"
     git -C "$plugin" pull
  fi
done
```

Comment: In the case, there is not custom themes or plugins inside the folder it will crash. Maybe add a check could be safer

Answer (score 2):

You can use [OhMyZsh Full-autoupdate](https://github.com/Pilaton/OhMyZsh-full-autoupdate) plugin.
It updates both plugins and themes.

Comment: This worked great! It works for both plugins and Themes